# Is there any support to create application using REST API?

Tags: mesibo

Can you please let me know , Do we have provision to create application through REST API. Like we have for users.

https://mesibo.com/documentation/api/backend-api/#mesibo-backend-api-url

Comment: there is a `setapp` API but it won't let you create unlimited apps. What is your use case?

Comment: My use case is to create app through api call and create users in the same app.

Comment: https://api.mesibo.com/api.php?name=<APPNAME>&d=1&op=appadd&key=<MASTERKEY>  - this is worked for me . Thank you